# Angular 4: changing url, but component is not rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, router, routerlink

I'm trying to link a component from one component using `routerLink = "selected"`

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'account',
            component: AccountComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'selected',
                component: SelectedComponent,
              },
            ],
          },

        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class AccountSettingsRoutingModule { }
```

This is AccountComponent

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-list-accounts',
      templateUrl: './accounts-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./accounts-list.component.scss']
    })
    export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
     ngOnInit() {}
}
```

The url is changing to the desired like this dashboard/account/selected, but the view is not loading.

Comment: Please, Share your html and component

Comment: Have you added <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html?

Comment: yes, it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to AccountComponent. Read more in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration).

Comment: added<router-outlet></router-outlet> to app.component.html and it works. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you upvote this an mark it as the solution to the question?

Comment: thank you , it is important to tell where component must be rendered